# How to calculate where an element should be without moving it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, positioning

I need to change the horizontal position of an element. To do this I change its `left` attribute with `.css('left', value)`. That would move the element relative to where it should be if there was no `left` value defined.

Now I need to recalculate the position to move the element somewhere else, to do that I need the position where the element should be if I had not changed its `left` attribute.

I could remove the `left` value and ask for its position but then the element would also move and would like to avoid that since I may make the element jump between positions.

How could I get the position where the element would be?

Comment: Why not `element.offset().left` - `parseInt( element.css('left').replace("px","") )`

Comment: @chumkiu `parseInt()` will work on the px value without the need for a `str.replace()`

Comment: @phonicx it seems you're right :-)

Comment: (1) keep some delta variables; or, (2) keep the initial position in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element doesn't jump between position if you change the `left` style multiple times. As long as your function is running, there are no updates in the browser. You can safely reset the `left` style, get the positon, and then set a new `left` value.

Comment: in the end I change the method for positioning the elements, I just used absolute positioning. Anyway your answer was the most useful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to read the default left value of the element on DOM-ready and add it to the element as a `data-*` attribute on the element - let's call it `data-default-left` or something similar. You could then always refer to that value when you need the default value further on.

The `data-*` are easy to work with using jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

Answer (score 0):

Setting left to 0, recalculating, and setting left to the new position would be the easiest change in your case. In my experience the browser will not repaint between css updates.

Some other options:

1. Use absolute positioning instead of relative. Then you're origin is consistent.
2. Use the [jQuery UI position plugin](http://jqueryui.com/position/). It lets you set the position of an element relative to another. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

how about use `.data()` to store this info before starting moving it? Then u just gather it back there everytime u need.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Store the initial left amount in a variable on dom load and then reference it later when you do your other calculations:

```
$(function () { 

    var $element = $("#ME_ELEMENT_ID");

    var initialLeft = $element.offset().left;

    // Change your left here

    $element.css('left', '200px');

    // initialLeft still contains the old value

});
```